# How can I make a plot disappear once an input is switched?

Tags: shiny

I would like to have the `output$plot` disappear once `input$type` is switched. In the reprex below, it currently only changes the title of the plot, which is misleading. How can I make the plot disappear?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("type", "type", c("Normal", "Uniform")),
  actionButton("go", "go"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  r <- reactive({
    if(input$type == "Normal"){
      rnorm(100)
    } else if (input$type == "Uniform"){
      runif(100)
    }
  }) |>
    bindEvent(input$go)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(r(), main = input$type, xlab = "x")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New Answer

Here's an option to force the plot to hide when `input$type` changes.

When `input$go` is observed, I save the value of `input$type` into a reactive value `rv` and set the specific data to the same reactive value. Once `input$type` changes, the new value != old value and thus NULL is returned in the plot. Finally, when clicking "go" the value of `input$type` now matches what's in the reactiveValue and a plot is returned.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # set reactive values for data, initialize, and plot type
  rv = reactiveValues(dat = NULL, type = NULL)
  
  # set plot type at the time "go" was clicked and data
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    sel_type = input$type
    rv$type = sel_type
    
    if(sel_type == "Normal"){
      rv$dat = rnorm(100)
    } else if (sel_type == "Uniform"){
      rv$dat = runif(100)
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$go
    # return nothing if the new plot type differs from the plot type when 'go' was last clicked
    if (input$type != rv$type || is.null(rv$type)) {
      NULL
    } else {
      hist(rv$dat, main = input$type, xlab = "x")
    }
  })
}
```

#### Old Answer

`output$plot` is dependent on `r()` and `input$type`. And `r()` is dependent on `input$go`.

When you change input$type, the renderPlot invalidates but since `input$go` has not yet been clicked, renderPlot returns the previous state of `r()` and the **new value** of input$type. To fix this wrap input$type with `isolate`.

```
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(r(), main = isolate(input$type), xlab = "x")
  })
```

Comment: Great, but how can I get the plot to disappear when the input type does not match the plot?

Comment: I've updated my response to remove the plot when the input changes.

Answer (score 1):

By putting the plot into `isolate()` function and putting a dependency to the `go` button you can prevent the unwanted change in the title. Then, whenever you click on the `go` button all the plot will be updated and I was wondering if you don't need to disappear the plot anymore in this case. But if you need the plot to be disappear anyway please let me know.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("type", "type", c("Normal", "Uniform")),
  actionButton("go", "go"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactive({
    if(input$type == "Normal"){
      rnorm(100)
    } else if (input$type == "Uniform"){
      runif(100)
    }
  }) |>
    bindEvent(input$go)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$go
    isolate({hist(r(), main = input$type, xlab = "x")})
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes having the plot disappear would be even better.